# Unable to convert Javascript object having a 0 key

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I want to convert this JavaScript object

```
var y = [{0:{Date:"Sep 24"}}]
```

to this `[{0:{Date:"Sep 23"}}]`

But I am not to figure it out. I tried to do this

```
y[0].0.Date = "Sep 23"
```

but it didn't work. Even though it works if I change 0 to Hell

```
var y = [{Hell:{Date:"Sep 24"}}]
y[0].Hell.Date = "Sep 23"
```

Comment: Can you try with: `y[0].['0'].Date = "Sep 23"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this `y[0]['0'].Date = "Sep 23"`

Explanation:

1. Select the first index of the array = `y[0]`
2. Select the required key using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) = `y[0]['0']`
3. Select the inner key = `y[0]['0'].Date`
4. Lastly, assign the value = `y[0]['0'].Date = "Sep 23"`

Comment: Doesn't need to be `['0']` since keys are stringified by default

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use `y[0][0]` instead of y[0].0

Answer (score 0):

If a property's name is a `Number`, you should reference it as you would an `Array` element.

```js
y[0][0].Date = 'Sep 23';
```

```js
const obj = {
  1: 'Hello'
  2: 'Goodbye'
};

console.log(obj.1); // this will return an error
```

```js
const obj = {
  1: 'Hello',
  2: 'Goodbye',
};

console.log(obj[1]); // this will not
```